# Can a mongodb secondary recover if the lag is larger then the oplog?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

Let's assume a secondary is fallen behind because of server crash that was not restarted within a given time. Now we have a lag of 100h but an oplog of 10h like this

```
db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

source: db3
    syncedTo: TIMEINTHEPAST
    360000 secs (100.00 hrs) behind the primary
source: db1
    syncedTo: NOW
    1 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

But then the oplog is much smaller

```
db.printReplicationInfo()

configured oplog size:   GIVENSIZE
log length start to end: 36000secs (10hrs)
```

Do I assume correctly that this secondary has no chance of catching up (RECOVERING)?

How is this situation to be resolved?

Comment: This really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). It's generally the cardinal sin to allow a secondary to fall behind the oldest item in the primary oplog. Naturally you cannot "play" transactions when you do not know they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is simple. Secondary cannot survive. In that situation you have few different possibilities to "re-initialize" that node.

- You stop that node, empty it's data directory, restart it and let it do initial sync.

OR

- You stop that node, bring snapshot (or data files) of other healthy nodes data files, restart it and let it "catch" the primary.

After you have again working replica set, [resize your oplog size to much bigger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/). Like 15 times bigger.